# Run function when Mac machine wakes

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-sierra

I'm looking for a function which will get called when a macOS machine wakes up from sleep.

What are some ways to achieve this?

I'm looking to run code in my Swift application when the computer awakens. I'm trying to open a new websocket when this happens. If I open the lid -> new websocket, if I press the any key -> new websocket.

What I've found useful so far is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34912943/4534012) which stems from what @Rob Napier has suggested (`didWakeNotification`)

Comment: What kind of machine?

Comment: Has to work for any machine, OS 10.10+

Comment: @JoshCaswell I'm not sure if these edits match the OP's original intent; it feels like a different question now. Is this what you meant, @OrangePot?

Comment: I basically just added the fact that we're talking about a Mac and cleaned up the title, @RobNapier. I don't see how [my edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46943012/4) changed the meaning.

Comment: This isn't a Swift-specific question. You're asking about the operating system, or the system frameworks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to give more information than this. Is this an user-level (GUI?) application that will be running when the machine goes to sleep? Is this a daemon? Do you expect your program to be launched if it isn't already running? Is the program sandboxed? Do you expect to have root access? What if no one is logged in? "Wakes up from sleep" has many subtle corner cases (for example, it includes a "dark wake" mode which are not quite sleep and not quite wake).

That said, the high-level answer is "observe `NSWorkspace.didWakeNotification`" and the low-level answer is "call `IORegisterForSystemPower`." But whether either of those help you depends a lot on what problem you're solving.